# Can anyone explain what this means?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone explain what this is supposed to do?
If possible maybe outline the first few results?
Its in part of a set theory question.

$$
\Pi_{1}^\infty\{0,1\}
$$

Comment: Can you explain us where this comes from?

Comment: My guess would be the set of all sequences with elements in $\{ 0, 1\}$. Another notation would be $\{ 0, 1\}^{\Bbb N}$

Comment: The answer has something about sequences, could you explain your answer and give an example maybe? @MartinR

Comment: @MartinR Also occasionally written as $\{0,1\}^\omega$.

Answer (score 2):

The Cartesian product of two sets is denoted $A \times B$. Its elements are all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ is an element of $A$ and $b$ is an element of $B$.

If we have $n$ sets $A_1, \ldots, A_n$, the Cartesian product of all the sets could be written $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$. It would consist of all ordered pairs $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ where $a_i$ is an element of $A_i$ for all $i$ between $1$ and $n$.

At this point, we make an analogy with multiplication. The product of the $n$ numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ could be written as $a_1 \times \cdots \times a_n$. A more compact way of writing the same thing is
$$
\prod_{i = 1}^n a_i
$$
which says to take the product of the $a_i$, starting with $1$ and ending with $n$. Since we already use $\times$ for the Cartesian product of sets, it seems reasonable to let
$$
\prod_{i = 1}^n A_i
$$
stand for the product $A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$, just as with multiplication.

If we have a set $A_n$ for every natural number $n$, then, with this notation, we can write the product of all the $A_n$ as
$$
\prod_{n = 1}^\infty A_n
$$
The elements of this set are all the ordered pairs $(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ where $a_n$ is an element of $A_n$ for every natural number $n$.

Finally, the set in your question is what we get if we take $A_n = \{0,1\}$ for every natural number $n$. In our notation, this looks like
$$
\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \{0,1\}
$$
(sometimes, as in your question, the $n = 1$ is abbreviated to $1$ when the index is understood). The elements of this set are all the ordered pairs $(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ where $a_n$ is an element of $A_n = \{0,1\}$ for every natural number $n$. That is, the elements of this set are all the ordered pairs $(a_1, a_2, \ldots )$ where $a_n$ is $0$ or $1$ for every natural number $n$. In words, $\prod_1^\infty \{0,1\}$ is the set of all infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s.